# Send Meda Data in request body for bpmn process

Tags: java, quarkus, jbpm, bpmn, bpmn.io

While starting a BPMN process using the API, we send process data in the request body. I want to include some metadata in the request body to distinguish between starting the BPMN process from the UI and through a backend service. Additionally, when starting the process through a backend service, I want to implement a two-way handshake mechanism between the sender and receiver processes. My plan is to use the metadata to identify the sender and acknowledge it after receiving it back from the receiver.
Are there any solutions that someone can suggest?

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.